# Unable to See ImageView with RecyclerView in a RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm attempting to create a simple image gallery with the thumbnails shown at the bottom using a RecyclerView and the large/detailed photo shown above it in an ImageView.

The problem is - the RecyclerView with the thumbnails is shown and created - however the large/detailed image is never shown, even when hardcoding it's background. I believe this to be an XML related issue - but I cannot seem to spot the problem.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/black_color"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MMSGallery">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detail_photo"
        android:background="@drawable/mms_img1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_images"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/detail_photo"
        android:background="@color/black_color" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

### Java:

```
public class SpaceGalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


     ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_space_gallery);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detail_photo);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load("http://i.imgur.com/zuG2bGQ.jpg")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .into(mImageView);


        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_images);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
      //  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));


        SpaceGalleryActivity.ImageGalleryAdapter adapter = new SpaceGalleryActivity.ImageGalleryAdapter(this, SpacePhoto.getSpacePhotos());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

....
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are setting `RecyclerView` to `match_parent`.which overlaps your **ImageView**

so change your layout to

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/activity_main"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detail_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/mms_img1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:id="@+id/rv_images"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/detail_photo"
        android:layout_below="@id/detail_photo"
        android:background="@color/black_color"
        />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would work for you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/detail_photo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/placeholder"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_images"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/detail_photo"
    android:background="@color/red_500" />
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Changing from a `RelativeLayout` to a `LinearLayout` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MMSGallery">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detail_photo"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_images"
        android:layout_below="@+id/detail_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"


        android:background="@color/black_color" />
</RelativeLayout>
```